# How best to update client table with latest server data

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am investigating whether we are using the best method of updating a customer waiting screen.

Currently, we have a system that customers can arrive, take a ticket and sit and wait.. Operators have a screen that shows waiting tickets. They can "call" those tickets from the application which then takes the ticket from the queue and it is dealt with.

The tech that runs this is an MVC application and razor views. The operators have a page with a table on it showing waiting tickets.

We have a jquery function called refreshtable(); that runs from a setInterval . The interval is 3 seconds.
refreshtable function uses jquery ajax to call a controller action that returns the latest set of data. The success action of that ajax then sets the html of the parent div to the new table data. the data is coming out of SQL. We have paired down the query that is returning the data and are pretty happy that it is efficient.

We have up to 10 "operators" with this screen constantly updating. It needs to be frequently updated as tickets are coming in and being called constantly. Slowing the refresh down will cause confusion amongst the operators.

Our problem lies in the fact that neither the operators pc's or the webserver are fantastically powerful. Ultimately we would chop the lot and put in a fresh set of gear, but this isn't currently an option on the table.
Are there any other client side technologies that I could consider using for this senario? i.e. knockout  or Angular?

All comments/views are most welcome.

Comment: web socket but seems useless in your case. FYI, you shouldn't use an interval to do ajax requests but instead a timeout which will be 'reinitialised' on each complete request to avoid any kind of race condition (if a request takes more than 3 seconds to complete)

Comment: How is a timeout that refreshes any less of a possible race condition that an interval ?

Answer (score 0):

Other client side tech like Knockout or Angular won't be of any real use to you as they won't address the heart of your problem.  What it sound like you are looking for is realtime communication between client and server, which basically isn't available via HTTP.

There is a good Question and Answer here that describes mechanisms that are available for the type of communication that you want.
[Is there a real server push over http?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8110550/is-there-a-real-server-push-over-http)

So in the end, to solve your problem you will want to use something like [websockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11424694/so-asp-net-mvc-and-websockets) but if your hardware / hosting environment is not up to date then you may not be able to make this work.  The other option would be to use some kind of desktop approach like WinForms / WPF which will give you a lot more flexibility, but of course that means a large rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

Use SignalR to update table without refreshing screen. [SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr)

Comment: I wondered about signalR. With the gear I have at my disposal (server 2003 webserver) and XP client machines running IE9 is there an advantage. I looked for a demo of using signalR to push to client when changes are detected in a sql table but couldn't quite find what I was after.